# knockout mapping (ko.mapping.fromJS()) not updating targets when async $.ajax call

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am trying to use ko.mapping to transform data to a viewmodel.  The result come from an async call to a web service.

Simple view:

```
<div data-bind="with: myData">
    <div data-bind="text: mapWidth"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: mapHeight"></div>
    <div data-bind="foreach: priceRanges">
    <div data-bind="text: title"></div>
</div>
```

AND the view model is as follows:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.myData = null;

    var data = {
        action: 'GetPricePoints',
        type: 'who cares'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://cdt.lotamore.com/api/imap',
        data: { "": JSON.stringify(data) },
        //async: false, // works!
        async: true, // doesn't work!!!!!
        type: 'post'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        self.myData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        alertError(data);
    })
    .always(function () {
    });
};
```

When I run this synchronously is works fine.  However, when I run it asynchronously it doesn't update the `myData` within my view model.

I have created a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jgergen/jF9pm/20/

I really don't want to make ajax calls that block the UI thread!
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I have changed the line:

```
    self.myData = null;
```

to:

```
    self.myData = ko.observable();
```

This is not all, I tried this before without favorable results.  In addition to making `myData` observable, I had to change the way it is updated.  Here is the new `.done` method:

```
    .done(function (d) {
        self.myData(ko.mapping.fromJS(d));
    })
```

So, what I needed to do is treat this field as I would any other observable.

You can see it here at this new fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jgergen/jF9pm/47/

I hope that this helps more than me.  I searched for a solution to this problem all over the web without any results.  So here it is.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: You may be interested to know why the async true/false was tripping you up.  The answer is that when async is false, myData will contain a value when you execute ko.applyBindings.  When async is true, myData will be updated AFTER ko.applyBindings executes.  Because myData was not observable, the binding would have been applied against null, and knockout is not able to observe changes after the async call completes.

Comment: @Jim that's the way to go :)

Comment: Move data fetching out from the constructor if you ask me. Its cleaner to bind the model after its initial data is fetched.